# Google Chrome extensions possibly messing up my development testing

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, google-chrome

I'm using several Chrome extension, some development, some games and other's like ABP, Trend Micro Toolbar and a few other's like REST, Postman, etc...

So I'm trying and test using code from JqueryUI and the Accordion widget will not work. The funny thing is, there are no errors in the dev console. Just an error for an extensions::uncaught_exception_handler:9.  This is in a JS file called: extensions:uncaught_exception_handler.

Where did this come from?

Here's my screen shot of the console:

[image]

Now the basic Accordion code which I'm implementing directly from the website: http://jqueryui.com/accordion/

That's it... what I get is this:

[image]

Now finally the code that "should" make the accordion work according to the link above:

```
<div id="accordion" class="ui-accordion">
    <h3 class="ui-accordion-header ui-accordion-header-icon">Section 1</h3>
    <div class="ui-accordion-content">
        <p>
            Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget, quam. Integer
            ut neque. Vivamus nisi metus, molestie vel, gravida in, condimentum sit
            amet, nunc. Nam a nibh. Donec suscipit eros. Nam mi. Proin viverra leo ut
            odio. Curabitur malesuada. Vestibulum a velit eu ante scelerisque vulputate.
        </p>
    </div>
    <h3 class="ui-accordion-header ui-accordion-header-icon">Section 2</h3>
    <div class="ui-accordion-content">
        <p>
            Sed non urna. Donec et ante. Phasellus eu ligula. Vestibulum sit amet
            purus. Vivamus hendrerit, dolor at aliquet laoreet, mauris turpis porttitor
            velit, faucibus interdum tellus libero ac justo. Vivamus non quam. In
            suscipit faucibus urna.
        </p>
    </div>
    <h3 class="ui-accordion-header ui-accordion-header-icon">Section 3</h3>
    <div class="ui-accordion-content">
        <p>
            Nam enim risus, molestie et, porta ac, aliquam ac, risus. Quisque lobortis.
            Phasellus pellentesque purus in massa. Aenean in pede. Phasellus ac libero
            ac tellus pellentesque semper. Sed ac felis. Sed commodo, magna quis
            lacinia ornare, quam ante aliquam nisi, eu iaculis leo purus venenatis dui.
        </p>
        <ul>
            <li>List item one</li>
            <li>List item two</li>
            <li>List item three</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE:  OK, I removed the CHROME Apps extension that all that error stuff above goes away but that still doesn't explain why the Accordion doesn't work and there are no errors.  The H3 tag (title of the panel) allows me to click but nothing happens anywhere.  I'm halfway there.

Oh yeah, I'm using Bootstrap 3.0 in this mix.  Here's my CSS loading order:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.css" />
<!-- This is bootstrap; Themerolled -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/bootstrap/lavish-bootstrap.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/font-awesome/font-awesome.css" />
<!-- Custom CSS only for my website -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/styleThumbs.css" />
<!-- Add fancyBox -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.5" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<!-- My own custom overrides -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/css-overrides-1.0.css" / >
```

Also: Here is the order of the JS files... I'm using JQ 1.11.1

```
<script src="../scripts/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="../scripts/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="../scripts/bootstrap/bootstrap.js"></script>
<!-- This is the loading JQUI features Script -->
<script src="../scripts/jquery-ui/custom-base-jquery-ui.js"></script>
<!-- This is the custom HOVERINT Script -->
<script src="../scripts/jquery-modals/accordion.js"></script>

 <!-- This is JQUERY Easing -->
 <script src="../scripts/jquery/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
 <!-- Fancy Box -->
 <script src="../scripts/jquery/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.5"></script>
 <script src="../scripts/pd-custom.js"></script>
```

SECOND UPDATE:  I initialize the accordion here:

```
$(function () {

    $("#accordion").accordion({
        heightStyle: "content",
        event: "click hoverintent",  //This is in the accordion.js file
        icons: icons
    });
});
```

Comment: Do you init the accordion? From the jquery-ui docs: `$( "#accordion" ).accordion();`

Comment: Yes, that's done from the file: custom-base-jquery-ui.js... see the Second UPDATE above.

Comment: Rofl derp, if its initialized from custom-base-jquery-ui.js why is the accordian plugin being loaded after it? Of course it wont recognize the initialization because it hasnt been created yet :)

Comment: Nope, I'm sorry to say, but the accordion.js script holds the "HOVERINT" feature only. The accordion is being initialized. I've reordered the JS files nine ways to sunday and still. No JS errors and the accordion feature doesn't work. I continue to get what you see in the second image.  I've even taken out the accordion.js and still no change and no errors.  Is it entirely possible since I'm preloading the js files through this:  <link rel="import" href="partials/js-files.html" /> be the problem? I don't believe so although the files are all loading successfully.

Comment: Well, there is obviously SOME problem. Try to strip down as much unnecessary code as possible. Here is a basic working example: http://jsfiddle.net/JimUBC/d6mSA/

Comment: I got it working before you even stated this... VERY COOL. I went down to the bare roots and found that it was "H1" tags sitting above the <div id="accordion"> tag that was messing things up. When I simply put that title in it's own div, the problem went away.  Thanks, all. Now who do I give credit to?

Comment: You found the problem, so describe it in an answer and accept it. Glad that you got that resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working before you even stated this... VERY COOL.

I went down to the bare roots and found that it was "H1" tags sitting above the

```
<div id="accordion">
```

tag that was messing things up.

When I simply put that title in it's own div, the problem went away.

Here's the solution:

```
    <div id="title">
        <h1>The Books...</h1>
        <h2>The AUTHOR</h2>
        <p>A collection of books published or currently in development</p>
    </div>
    <hr/>
    <div id="accordion">
        <h3>Section 1</h3>
        <div>
            <p>
                Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget, quam. Integer
                ut neque. Vivamus nisi metus, molestie vel, gravida in, condimentum sit
                amet, nunc. Nam a nibh. Donec suscipit eros. Nam mi. Proin viverra leo ut
                odio. Curabitur malesuada. Vestibulum a velit eu ante scelerisque vulputate.
            </p>
        </div>
        <h3>Section 2</h3>
        <div>
            <p>
                Sed non urna. Donec et ante. Phasellus eu ligula. Vestibulum sit amet
                purus. Vivamus hendrerit, dolor at aliquet laoreet, mauris turpis porttitor
                velit, faucibus interdum tellus libero ac justo. Vivamus non quam. In
                suscipit faucibus urna.
            </p>
        </div>
        <h3>Section 3</h3>
        <div>
            <p>
                Nam enim risus, molestie et, porta ac, aliquam ac, risus. Quisque lobortis.
                Phasellus pellentesque purus in massa. Aenean in pede. Phasellus ac libero
                ac tellus pellentesque semper. Sed ac felis. Sed commodo, magna quis
                lacinia ornare, quam ante aliquam nisi, eu iaculis leo purus venenatis dui.
            </p>
            <ul>
                <li>List item one</li>
                <li>List item two</li>
                <li>List item three</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```